# Failed to retrieve long data for column varbinary (max)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

We have created several packages using the import utility of MS SQL 2016. In each import, we are copying data from a SQL 2016 database to another SQL 2016 database with the same database schema. All the packages are working fine except one. In this one import, we are copying a column of varbinary(max). When I execute this import using import utility, everything works fine. When I execute this as a SQL agent job, it fails with the error: Failed to retrieve long data for column "Samples"  Code: 0xC020901C on the source. In the XML of the import .dtsx, I see that the column is intepreted as dataType="image". Should I change this datatype? How can I make this work from the agent?

Comment: I do not know this special constellation, but the data type `IMAGE` is outdated for centuries... If possible, change this to `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

Answer (score 0):

A team mate had found the answer: The proxy credentials did not have access to write to the temp directory of the SQL Server Agent account. Temp directory was necessary for writing the varbinary column. We didn't realise that the temp directory was being used and although the tasks were running under the proxy credential, SQL server agent account was being used for the temp folder.